# Is k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm used a lot in real life?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am teaching myself machine learning through the book "Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists", and I am currently at the k-Nearest Neighbors section. The authors mention that this algorithm is rarely used in real life due to "prediction being slow and its inability to handle many features". However, the k-Nearest Neighbors is mentioned as one of the most popular algorithms for data scientist in many articles. So, could somebody explain it for me here?

Comment: Mostly in unsupervised learning it makes sense for basic approach. To be more precise when you have very less data and you need specific prediction like top n items with common features then it's most basic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-nearest neighbor has a lot of application in machine learning because of the nature of the problem which is solved by a k-nearest neighbor. In other words, the problem of the k-nearest neighbor is fundamental and it is used in a lot of solutions. For example, in data representation such as tSNE, to run the algorithm we need to compute the k-nearest neighbor of each point base on the predefined perplexity.

Also, you can find more application of kNN [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) and its application in the industry in the last page of [this article](https://www.ijera.com/papers/Vol3_issue5/DI35605610.pdf).

> The KNN algorithm is one of the most popular
>   algorithms for text categorization or **text mining**.
>
> Another interesting application is the evaluation of forest
>   inventories and for estimating forest variables. In
>   these applications, satellite imagery is used, with the
>   aim of mapping the land cover and land use with few
>   discrete classes. The other applications of the k-NN
>   method in **agriculture** include climate forecasting and
>   estimating soil water parameters.
>
> Some of the other applications of KNN in **finance** are
>   mentioned below:
>
> - Forecasting stock market: Predict the price of a
>     stock, on the basis of company performance
>     measures and economic data.
> - Currency exchange rate
> - Bank bankruptcies
> - Understanding and managing financial risk
> - Trading futures
> - Credit rating
> - Loan management
> - Bank customer profiling
> - Money laundering analyses
>
> **Medicine**
>
> - Predict whether a patient, hospitalized due to a
>     heart attack, will have a second heart attack. The
>     prediction is to be based on demographic, diet
>     and clinical measurements for that patient.
> - Estimate the amount of glucose in the blood of a
>     diabetic person, from the infrared absorption
>     spectrum of that person’s blood.
> - Identify the risk factors for prostate cancer,
>     based on clinical and demographic variables.
>
> The KNN algorithm has been also applied
>   for analyzing micro-array gene expression data,
>   where the KNN algorithm has been coupled with
>   genetic algorithms, which are used as a search tool.
>   Other applications include the prediction of solvent
>   accessibility in protein molecules, the detection of
>   intrusions in computer systems, and the management
>   of databases of moving objects such as computer
>   with wireless connections.